# Inserting Values (Sudoku Grid)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a  9x9 sudoku grid, and each box has an input element assigned to it.

When I set the values in the box and try to inspect the input element I notice that the `innerHTML` property is empty (`""`).

This is where I am stuck, why is input element not picking the values that I enter?

Here's my JS:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var grid = [];
    setInputBox();
    document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(){
        solve(grid);
    }

};


function setInputBox(){
    var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for(var prop in inputElements){
        if(inputElements[prop].innerHTML = " "){
            inputElements[prop].innerHTML += '<input type="number" min="1" max="9"/>';
        }
    }
}

var solve = function(grid){
    grid = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    console.log(grid);
//        for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
//            for(var j = 0; i < 9; j++){
//
//                if(checkValidity(grid,i,j)){
//                    console.log('valid');
//                }
//                else{
//                    console.log('invalid');
//                }
//            }
//        }
    }
```

Comment: im not quite clear on what you are asking, but, the text in the input element is stored in its value, not innerHtml if thats what you meant...

Comment: If you provided the relevant HTML it would help.

Comment: @Banana the input type is number

Comment: @user3750842 doesnt matter. `<input type="number" onchange="alert(this.value);"></input>`

Comment: @Banana just realized i am not firing the change event

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your "input" is, I'm assuming they are `<input type="text">`?

If so, then you'll need to use `.value` instead of `.innerHTML`

`.innerHTML` is used to get all the HTML within a tag.

**IE**

```
<form>
    <input type="number" class="whatever"> 
</form>
```

This doesn't really have any "inner html" within the input tag, because it's its own element. You'd want the VALUE of that element, not the contents of the tag.

**However**

```
<div id="whatever">
   <a href="#">link text</a>
</div>
```

You could get the `.innerHTML` of the `<a>` tag here, because there are contents between the opening and closing tags... meaning there is HTML on the inside (aka innerHTML)

Comment: input type  is 'number'

Comment: @user3750842 In that case you'll still use `.value` in place of `.innerHTML`